# Remove unnecessary white spaces in brackets and braces

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a bunch of sentences where additional white spaces are presented in every pair of brackets/parentheses/braces. Some of the brackets/parentheses/braces overlap with each other, which is giving me problems. e.g.:

```
[in]: sentence = '{ ia } ( { fascia } antebrachii ). Genom att aponeurosen fäster i armb'
[in]: pattern = r'(\s([?,.!"]))|(?<=\{|\[|\()(.*?)(?=\)|\]|\})'
[in]: re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group().strip(), sentence)
[out]: '{ia} ({ fascia} antebrachii ). Genom att aponeurosen fäster i armb'
```

As shown here, I have failed to remove the unnecessary white spaces in the overlapped brackets/parentheses/braces. How do I cover these overlapping or nested cases? Thanks.

```
Expected output:
'{ia} ({fascia} antebrachii). Genom att aponeurosen fäster i armb'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace any space following an opening bracket, or preceding a closing bracket with this regex:

```regex
(?<=[\[{(])\s+|\s+(?=[\]})])
```

`(?<=[\[{(])\s+` - looks for spaces preceded by one of `[{(`

`\s+(?=[\]})])` - looks for spaces followed by one of `]})`

In python

```py
sentence = '{ ia } ( { fascia } antebrachii ). Genom att aponeurosen fäster i armb'
re.sub(r'\s+(?<=[\[{(])|\s+(?=[\]})])', '', sentence)
```

Output:

```
{ia} ({fascia} antebrachii). Genom att aponeurosen fäster i armb
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
" +(?=[^(]*\))| +(?=[^{]*\})"
```

Explanation:

1. `+` look for one or more spaces
2. `(?=[^(]*\)` positive look ahead to check if the the preceding space
   is inside a first bracket.
3. `|` or
4. `+` look for one or more spaces
5. `(?=[^{]*\})`  positive look ahead to check if the the preceding
   space is inside a curly bracket.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6FqS0d/1)

Python source ( [run here](https://ideone.com/2b1CuO) ):

```
regex = r" +(?=[^(]*\))| +(?=[^{]*\})"
test_str = ("{ ia } ( { fascia  } antebrachii ). Genom att aponeurosen \n")
result = re.sub(regex,"", test_str)
if result:
    print (result)
```

Comment: Thanks! The output is not what I wanted. It removed the white space between words which is legitimate and does not need to be removed. The expected output is `'{ia} ({fascia} antebrachii). Genom att aponeurosen fäster i armb'`